# Dictionary<AnyHashable: Any> where Any may hold nil value in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, swift-dictionary

Can someone explain why this works in Swift 3?

```
var dict: [AnyHashable: Any]
let b: AnyObject? = nil
let c = b as Any

dict = ["a": "aa", "b": c]
```

If I test

`dict["b"] == nil`

It returns false. Is it supposed to be right?

Comment: Using `nil` as a dictionary value in Swift is nonsense because by definition setting a key to `nil` removes the key.

Comment: I know. The point is: someway I get a dictionary with a `nil` value and cannot remove it, because the check `dict[key] == nil` always returns false

Comment: Why don't you us it as an optional and check
`if let _ = dict["b"]`.  This is always a preferred check in swift

Comment: Interesting... Too many compiler magic here. `c` is `Any?`, which is not `nil` because `c` has a value. But the value is `nil`.

Comment: Setting it to nil via `dict[key] = nil` indeed removes the value. However a dict can hold an "Optional" as its type. It leads to confusing behavior with the subscript syntax, but you could still do something like `dict.updateValue(nil, forKey: "a")` to set a nil value. A dict with optionals is not really recommended at all though for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the latest Xcode, 8.1 (8B62) with Swift 3.0.1 .

`Any` containing `nil` is not so easy as simple nested optional:

#### Nested Optional

```
var dictWithOptional: [String: AnyObject?] = [
    "a": "aa" as NSString,
    "b": nil,
]
if let b = dictWithOptional["b"] { //<-check if `dict` contains value for "b"
    print(b) //->nil (with compiletime warning)
    print(b == nil) //->true
}
```

`b == nil` returns `true`.

#### `Any` containing `nil`

```
var dict: [AnyHashable: Any]
let b: AnyObject? = nil
let c = b as Any
dict = ["a": "aa", "b": c]

print(Array(dict.keys)) //->[AnyHashable("b"), AnyHashable("a")]
if let b = dict["b"] { //<-check if `dict` contains value for "b"
    print(b) //->nil
    print(b == nil) //->false (with compiletime warning)
}
```

`b == nil` becomes `false` as written by the OP.

You can detect `nil` in `Any`, with something like this:

```
if let b = dict["b"] { //<-check if `dict` contains value for "B"
    if b as AnyObject === NSNull() {
        print("b is nil") //->b is nil
    }
}
```

(This works in Swift 3.0.1, not in Swift 3.0.0 .)

Answer (score 2):

You're running into nested optionals. If a dictionary holds a type `E`, then the dictionary access method returns a value of type `E?`, either the value if it exists, or nil.

In your case, you've created a dictionary where the value is an optional. So the `E` above is something like `Any?`. This means the return value of the getter is `E?` i.e., `Any??`

In your case, `dict["b"]` returns a non-nil optional, containing the value 'nil'

Putting your code in a playground and printing `dict["b"]` confirms this by printing the string `Optional(nil)`